# Why does this regex need a space?

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex pattern that seems to require a space in it to work but I can't figure out why. Here's a test method I've made, I want to match the characters between the two `'`, but only when it is surrounded by the other characters and with optional spaces throughout.

```
Private Sub RegexTestSub()

    Dim testString = "Foo = ASSIGN/ 'Bar'"

    Dim patternA = "(?<=Foo([ ]+)?=([ ]+)?ASSIGN\/([ ']+)?)[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+(?=([' ]+)?)"
    Dim patternB = "(?<=Foo([ ]+)?=([ ]+)?ASSIGN\/ ([ ']+)?)[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]+(?=([' ]+)?)"

    Dim resultA As Match = Regex.Match(testString, patternA)
    Dim resultB As Match = Regex.Match(testString, patternB)

End Sub
```

Both match but the `resultB.Value` equals "Bar" but `resultA.Value` is just a space. The only difference between the regex patterns is the space after `ASSIGN\/` (that I'm aware of!) I want this space to be optional, which I thought the `([ ']+)?` would achieve.

Other examples that should match...

`Foo=ASSIGN/'Bar'` should match `Bar`

`Foo = ASSIGN/'Bar'` (Could be multiple spaces) should match `Bar`

`Foo = ASSIGN/ 'Foo.Bar.Foo.A1-0'` should match `Foo.Bar.Foo.A1-0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first regex matches the space because the lookbehind condition is met (that pattern is found right before the space) and the lookahead - `(?=([' ]+)?)` - makes no difference whatsoever since it requires an optional pattern, it may be there or not, and is thus totally redundant.

I think you need

```
(?<=Foo *= *ASSIGN/ *')[^']+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DFoo%20*%3D%20*ASSIGN%2F%20*%27%29%5B%5E%27%5D%2B&i=Foo%20%3D%20ASSIGN%2F%20%27Bar%27%0D%0AFoo%3DASSIGN%2F%27Bar%27%0D%0AFoo%20%3D%20ASSIGN%2F%27Bar%27%0D%0AFoo%20%3D%20ASSIGN%2F%20%27Foo.Bar.Foo.A1-0%27%20)

**Details**:

- `(?<=Foo *= *ASSIGN/ *')` - the location must be preceded with `Foo`, 0+ spaces, `=`, 0+ spaces, `ASSIGN/` and zero or more spaces
- `[^']+` - 1+ chars other than `'`

*Note* that if you need no overlapping matches, you may use *capturing* and use

```
Foo *= *ASSIGN/ *'([^']+)
```

and grab Group 1 (`match.Groups(1).Value`) value.

**If the data can come without single quotes**, and you need to get any chunk of 1+ non-whitespace chars after that lookbehind, I suggest using

```
Foo *= *ASSIGN/ *(?:'(?<v>[^']+)'|(?<v>\S+))
```

and grat the `v` group contents. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Foo+*%3d+*ASSIGN%2f+*%28%3f%3a%27%28%3f%3cv%3e%5b%5e%27%5cn%5d%2b%29%27%7c%28%3f%3cv%3e%5cS%2b%29%29&i=Foo+%3d+ASSIGN%2f+Bar%0d%0aFoo+%3d+ASSIGN%2f+%27Bar%27%0d%0aFoo%3dASSIGN%2f%27Bar%27%0d%0aFoo+%3d+ASSIGN%2f%27Bar%27%0d%0aFoo+%3d+ASSIGN%2f+%27Foo.Bar.Foo.A1-0%27+).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly and is a lot clearer to read! The string I need will always be surrounded by the single quotes so the first option is great.

Comment: I think you can do without a lookbehind here. Just capture the data you need with `(...)`

Comment: I need the look behind to check the parameter being assigned, I'm parsing a programming language for assignment of a specific parameter (In this case `Foo`) and getting the string assigned to the parameter (Always surrounded by single quotes)